# Software for a SmartMirror application with face recognition and voice control

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, web-server

I would like to create a Smartmirror. I want to define some standard "Widgets" which display information. But I also want to make it possible to create new widgets in runtime via xml, html/js or similiar (For example if you want to use another weather service or create an own basic widget).

I would like to configure the SmartMirror via a phone (Widget layout, WiFi password etc.)
The information that shall be displayed are:
 - Weather
 - Messages
 - List item
 - Traffic information
 - Netflix/YouTube

To control the smart mirror I want to use voice commands. Starting with voice detection of single command words going further to a "alexa like" control. (Of course I wouldn't program it by myself and use an aviable library)

I also want to use face recognition to display personalized screens. Person 1 sees sports new and the clock while Person 2 sees traffic information and stocks.

My plattform is a raspberry pi 3B+ and I have programming experience in C# and JavaScript.